# Run a preloader before loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

I have the following code:

```
$('.tudo').on('click', function (e) {               
                    myApp.showPreloader();


                    sessionStorage.clicados = "[]";
                    var clicados = [];                  

                    var visiveis  = $('.thumbnail').filter(':visible'); 

                    for(var i=0; i<visiveis.length;i++){

                        var url_img = $(visiveis[i]).attr('data-url');
                        var tipo = $(visiveis[i]).attr('data-tipo');
                        var idvideo = $(visiveis[i]).attr('data-idvideo');

                        clicados.push({
                            url_img: url_img,
                            tipo: tipo,
                            idvideo: idvideo
                        });                             
                    }


                    $(visiveis).find('img').addClass('thumb-selecionado');
                    sessionStorage.clicados = JSON.stringify(clicados);


                    var thumb_selecionados = $('.thumb-selecionado').length;
                    $('.contador').html(thumb_selecionados);

                    myApp.hidePreloader();
                });
```

My code run a loop to get attributes from `.thumbnail` class and save them inside a sessionStorage in JSON format

But, look at `myApp.showPreloader()`. This function shows a preloader in the screen but, for any reason, work **only when loop finish**, that is, the function freeze and run when it should end.

How i do to run the preloader function before loop start withou freeze?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes made by showPreloader won't appear until the thread exits, that's because the system doesn't get a chance to update the display.

You can instead call showPreloader, then do the lengthy operation in a setTimeout

https://jsfiddle.net/spuox3nu/2/

```
$(function(){
  $('#a').text('Please wait...');
  setTimeout(function(){
    //This takes a long time
    for(var i=0;i<1e9;i++){}
    $('#a').text('Finished, thank you for your patience.');  
  },0)
})
```

Everything after  `myApp.showPreloader();` goes in the setTimeout function.